Disagreement between two methods of computing the determinant of a differential operator
I want to compute the determinant of the following operator over the interval $[0,L]$:
\begin{equation}
A=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\omega^2.
\end{equation}
I imposed the boundary conditions $\phi(0)=\phi(L)=0$. The eigenvalues and orthonormal eigenmodes  are given by:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_n=\omega^2+(\frac{n\pi}{L})^2,~~~\phi_n=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})
\end{equation}
first method: The regularized determinant can be computed as follows:
\begin{equation}
\frac{det(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+\omega^2)}{det(-\frac{d^2}{dx^2})}=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+(\frac{\omega L}{n\pi})^2)=\frac{sinh(\omega L)}{\omega L}.
\end{equation}
In the large $L$ limit $L\to\infty$, the determinant will be simplified as $\sim\frac{e^{\omega L}}{2\omega L}$
Second method: I just want to calculate the above product in large $L\to\infty$ limit in the following way
\begin{equation}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+(\frac{\omega L}{n\pi})^2)=Exp\big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Log(1+(\frac{\omega L}{n\pi})^2)\big).
\end{equation}
We can estimate the sum with a integral as follows :
\begin{equation}
k_n=\frac{n\pi}{L},~~~~~k_{n+1}-k_n=\frac{\pi}{L}
\end{equation}
and in the large $L$ limit, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Log(1+(\frac{\omega L}{n\pi})^2)=\frac{L}{\pi}\lim_{L\to\infty}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}{L}Log(1+(\frac{\omega L}{n\pi})^2)\Big)=\frac{L}{\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{L}}^{\infty}dk Log(1+\frac{\omega^2 }{k^2})=\lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{2}{\pi}\omega L~arctan(\frac{\omega L}{\pi})-Log(1+\frac{(\omega L)^2}{\pi^2})\sim\omega L-2log(\frac{\omega L}{\pi})
\end{equation}
the integral is computed by Mathematica.
So the determinant is just the exponential of the above sum and is given by
\begin{equation}
\sim \pi^2\frac{e^{\omega L}}{(\omega L)^2}.
\end{equation}
The first method is true and can be found in the literatures and I want to know the error in the second method.

I’m voting to close this question because it was mistakenly migrated from Phys.SE, and should be migrated back.

Yes the question and the reasoning within it have the flavor of a physics question. (No criticism meant, after all, even the Clay Institute likes those questions...)

@Qmechanic, It would be great if I know your insight to this question.

You simply can not extract a factor L and do a limit $1/L ...$

Also, the next step (replacing the sum with an integral) does not seem to be accurate, even though an "$=$" sign is placed between them. And finally, you might want to post the Mathematica input lines that support your claim about the result of that integral.

@Jos Bergervoet, consider the partition of the interval $[\frac{\pi}{L},\infty]$ with the same length $\frac{\pi}{L}$ and take the $k$ as $k=\frac{\pi n}{L}$, I think this the same as the definition of the Riemann integral and the integral is the same as that sum.

@RolandF don't do the limit and just suppose that L is a very large number, the parenthesis is just an approximation of the mentioned integral with the partition of the interval $[\frac{\pi}{L},\infty]$ with the length $x_{j+1}-x_j=\frac{\pi}{L}$ between two neighbor points. I don't think that that point invalidates of the result.

@Ervand No, the Riemann integral only becomes the sum if the integrand changes relatively little in each sum term. Your shrinking of the intervals fails to do that if the lower bound $\pi/L$ is simultneously shifted to $0$, making the integrand blow up at those small values. Apart from that I think we would get the Mathematica result when using for instance L/Pi Series[Integrate[Log[1+w^2/k^2], {k,Pi/L,Infinity}], {L,Infinity,2}, Assumptions->{w>0,L>0}], simplify a bit and ignore the constant term $-2$. So I guess the only problem is with those early terms in the sum.
